# Cannot read jks file in site, 403 error, server linux -tomcat & nginx

Tags: nginx, tomcat, debian, gnupg, jks

few days ago, I made an upgrade gnupg in linux server. Since then, web applications that are placed on the server tomcat 8 -> nginx 10 have stopped working. After installing a new tomcat instance, the apps work except for logging in via SSO (where I use .jks certs)
Does anyone know what could have happened? What is needed on the server for these certificates to work?

I tried to look for an error on the web browser (F12), but there is nothing specific there, as well as in tomcat access logs for a given domain

Comment: Could you please provide bit more detail on what you are attempting to do and what is not happening. The .jks are usually java key store files where certificates are stored for SSL use. 403 is forbidden, what exactly were you trying to access.